# Delete multiple rows of Table in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have angularjs table added with check boxes to each row and a common remove button outside the table, so that multiple rows can be selected and deleted at a time. When rows are selected and remove is clicked, that particular rows will be deleted. This is fine and till here its working in the below plunker too. Now what I need is when a particular row is selected, its rowid has to be sent as a parameter to another URL. when this URL(URL formed by selected rowIds) with ids is called, automatically the rows will be deleted from first URL data, and now the table has to be updated from first URL. `null` will be returned from second url with ids as parameters and at the same time that rows will be deleted from JSON data of first URL.

Here is a `demo`:http://plnkr.co/edit/UzKdIGSubEfHoF7FHoCd?p=preview

Below is the code for the table:

```
<div ng-controller="SampleController">   

<form class="form-horizontal">
    <a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="subt_click()">Submit</a>
</form>    
<div class="table-responsive" ng-show="tableData.length > 0"> 
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example"> 
        <thead> 
            <tr> 
            <th><input name="all" type="checkbox" ng-click="selectAllFriends()" /></th>
                <th>ID</th> 
                <th>Body</th> 
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
            <tr ng-repeat="x in tableData"> 
           <td><input name="all" type="checkbox" ng-model="x.checked" /></td>
                <td>{{x.id}}</td> 
                <td>{{x.body}}</td> 
            </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table>        
</div>  
   <input ng-hide="!tableData.length" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" ng-click="remove()" value="Remove">
```

app.js:

```
   $scope.remove = function () {
    var newDataList = [];
    $scope.selectedAll = false;
    angular.forEach($scope.tableData, function (checked) {
        if (!checked.checked) {
            newDataList.push(checked);
        }
    });
    $scope.tableData = newDataList;
};

$scope.isAll = false;
$scope.selectAllFriends = function () {
    if ($scope.isAll === false) {
        angular.forEach($scope.tableData, function (x) {

            x.checked = true;
        });
        $scope.isAll = true;
    } else {
        angular.forEach($scope.tableData, function (x) {
            x.checked = false;
        });
        $scope.isAll = false;
    }
};
```

In brief what i need is:

1. I get table data from first url. (pls check the plunk and the url i used is jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)
2. When a checkbox is selected from a row in table and remove button is clicked, that rowid has to be sent to second URL(need to call another url, need not post) and this url when called along with selected rowids deletes that particular row details from first url and returns a null.
3. Finally, the first url data(which will be modified by just calling second url with rowids) has to be updated in the table present already.

How can I change this code to send rowid to second url and call that url to update the table. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: add some data in plunker

Comment: @dgk: Url am using is from a local host.. except that I have added all the code in the plunker.

Comment: create some hardcode data as per your response. Set in table.data. So i can help after see some data

Comment: $scope.selection.each(function (obj) {
         $scope.tableContent.splice(obj, 1)
      });
Use this in remove method

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/WwDjn5MByX41SBAA8OUA?p=preview
I updated the fork hope you will integrate with your code.

Comment: @dgk: Pls see this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/A5br22IUCT7JnwKGLWpC?p=preview here when u click on submit, a table with remove option will be displayed. when the rows are selected and remove is clicked.. the selected row ids has to be sent as parameter to another url(URL-A in plunk). when this url with ids is called.. automatically they will be deleted from url data.. and now the table has to be updated without these deleted rows.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.xListNo` is never affected in your statements.
May be you wanted to use `xListNo` which is your function parameter (without `$scope`) ?
So does `index` in your second statement, which should be `idx`.

Double check your variables spelling and it should work !

Comment: Updated the code but Its not working. Iam able to retrieve ListNo of the selected rows, but the remove part is not working.

Comment: Try to update the remove part with `$scope.tableContent.splice(xListNo, 1);`. I didn't see that you're passing the $index to the method.

Comment: Updated the code as u have suggested.. but still nothing is happening on clicking remove button

Comment: I didn't look at your html, but it can't work. Your button is outside of the ng-repeat tag, but it refers the $index which is on your ng-repeat's scope. If your button is supposed to allow the deletion of multiple rows at once, you need to store each ID in an array and iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

@Deborah : Went through your Plunker and could not find any code for Posting ids to an URL. Assuming that you are doing that somewhere, Still there can be two cases, whether to remove data as soon as call is made or removing it after response from API call. The better way would be removing after the success of API.

So, what you should do probably is to keep your entire table data in a variable (as you have already done, after your GET call).

```
//Table Data
        $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .success( function(response) {
            $scope.tableData = response;
        });
```

Now In remove function you can create an array of rows which are checked and send them to URL..Like:

```
  $scope.remove = function(){
        $scope.deletedIds = [];
          $scope.tableData.forEach(function(x){
          if(x.checked){
          $scope.deletedIds.push(x)
         }
        }
        makePostCallFOrDeletion()
    }

//use this if POST call
    function makePostCallFOrDeletion(){
     $http.post("deleteurl", angular.toJson($scope.deleteIds)).then(function(response){

    $scope.tableData = response //assuming you get the updated JSON back.
    //if you don't get JSON back, delete yourself from JSON, like

        $scope.tableData.forEach(function(x,i){
         if ($scope.deleteIds.indexOf(x.id) !== -1)
           $scope.tableData.splice(i, 1);
        }

    }
```

As per my understanding of your question, this should get you going..

EDIT: OP wanted GET call for deleting (which as per my opinion is not a good idea, since number of IDs can be too large)

```
//use this if GET call
function makePostCallFOrDeletion(){
     $http.get("deleteurl" + append IDs here,).then(function(response){

    //$scope.tableData = response //assuming you get the updated JSON back.
    //if you don't get JSON back, delete yourself from JSON, like

        $scope.tableData.forEach(function(x,i){
         if ($scope.deleteIds.indexOf(x.id) !== -1)
           $scope.tableData.splice(i, 1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I get `$scope.tableData.forEach is not a function` error on using above code.

Comment: yeah..that may be because your original data might not be array. But since you are using tableData in an ng-repeat, I believe that should be array.  Its better to have such data in arrays. Anyways, Can you show us what is the structure of tableData

Comment: When the second URL with selected ids is called `null` is returned from url. Here I need not post any data, whenever the second URL is called(using httpget()) with selected ids, that complete row details will be automatically  deleted from JSON of first URL. And the resulltant json from first url has to be displayed in table.

Comment: As I mentioned in my Answer, if you are not getting JSON back, you can delete manually. Just remove `$scope.tableData = response` from `.then` block and change it to get call. However, its always a good way to post such data instead of GET. What if user selects 100s of IDs to delete.